# template to_string << operator does not work for enum class

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I have a class that wraps a std::map, I have simplified it below. I wanted to implement a to_string() function which streams the first and second map entries into a stringstream with operator `<<` - then returns the string result.

This works ok for int, float, string etc... anything that can be streamed basically.

But `enum class xzy : int {...};` can't be stream -or it must be static_cast first. But in my template if I put static_cast around `x.second` then it will break other template types.

I want to know how I can deal with this. My first idea is to try to use type traits to detect if the type is integral (and then static cast it) otherwise just rely on the normal `operator <<` function.

here is the class:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class map_wrapper
{
public:
    std::map<T1, T2> m_map;
    std::map<T1, T2> &map() {return m_map;}
    std::string to_string()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        for (const auto &item : m_map)
        {
            // <----------------------- ISSUE HERE
            // So I want this to handle as many types as possible
            // Maybe I can do some sort of if type traits == integral then static cast?
            ss << item.first << ", " << static_cast<int>(item.second) << "\n";
            //ss << item.first << ", " << item.second << "\n";
        }
        return ss.str();
    }
};
```

here is my test code:

```cpp
enum class types : int
{
    type1,
    type2,
    type3
};

int main()
{
    // This is all ok
    map_wrapper<int, int> int_map;
    int_map.map() = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    std::cout << int_map.to_string() << std::endl;

    // This only works if I static_cast the enum types to an int within to_string()
    map_wrapper<int, types> type_map;
    type_map.map() = {{1, types::type1}, {2, types::type2}};
    std::cout << type_map.to_string() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have annotated the parts that don't work as I want them to.

Live editable example: https://godbolt.org/z/rh8Y5v

#### update

Note the types enum is just an example - I would like it to work with any enum class ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specialize a single member function, you would need to specialize the whole class. If you only need it for this function, I suggest providing a template operator overload:

```
template<typename Enum,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<Enum>>>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Enum e)
{
    return out << static_cast<int>(e);
}
```

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jbZhQWh7aeIpZoY7)

This operator will accept any `enum` or `enum class`. If you want to only accept `enum class`, you can use [`std::is_scoped_enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scoped_enum) from C++23 or roll out your own one (there's a possible implementation in cppreference to help).

Note that you can still provide overloads if you want to pretty print a particular enum (which would require another full class specialization if we went with that).

Comment: This live example is the same as my previous code with an extra function added that is not used. If I remove the static_cast in the to_string() it still fails to compile... so I am not sure what your solution is - what am I missing? (see: https://godbolt.org/z/Mb5dE4) The `is_scoped_enum` trait looks interesting - but AFAIK that is a c++23 feature so I have not got access to that yet :(

Comment: ok I think there was just a typeo in your code: this weems to work: https://godbolt.org/z/Pnzveq

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. That explains why it compiled with the typo. `std::is_enum` can be used instead of `std::is_scoped_enum` - explicit cast won't hurt. I'll update it in a moment.

Comment: yeah I just thought of that and tried: `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<Enum>>>` with your template function - that works nicely thanks! :)